# How i can change a css of an input["file"]?

Tags: html, css

This is how i have:

```
<!-- Files button -->
        <span class="new">+ Añadir archivos</span>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#in-btn").hover(function()
                {
                    $(".new").addClass("blue-blue");
                });

                $("#in-btn").mouseleave(function()
                {
                    $(".new").removeClass("blue-blue");
                });
            });

          $('#in-btn').change(function(){
            var files = $(this)[0].files;
            var text= " Archivos añadidos";
            if(files.length > 250){
                alert("250 archivos máximos");
            }else{
                var num_archivos = files.length + text;
                $("#num_archivos").text(num_archivos);
            }
         });

        </script>
```

Don't care about javascript, this is another thing. I use it to send a text message with the number of files selected.

This is my css:
There are two inputs files. The normal one, and the input file with ID.

```
 input[type="file"]{
position: relative;}

#in-btn{
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
cursor: pointer;
border: 1px solid;
z-index: 100;
width: 15%;
height: 25px;}

.new{
position: relative;
background: #526ed9;
padding: 10px 25px;
color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 50px;
font-size: 14px;}

.new:hover{
background: #2d4ecb;
-webkit-transition:background 0.3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:background 0.3s ease-in-out;
transition:background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;}

.blue-blue{
background: #2d4ecb;
-webkit-transition:background 0.3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:background 0.3s ease-in-out;
transition:background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;}
```

Comment: How i can add the css in this page as code?

Comment: that's not CSS, that's JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Siva has suggested, add `<style>` tag in the head of your html file.
define #in-btn and add the style rules into it as shown bellow:

```
<style>
#in-btn {
display:block;
background-color: #FFF;
padding: 5px;
...
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add it inside `<style>` tag in your HMTL. For ex:

```
<style>
body {background-color:lightgrey;}
h1   {color:blue;}
p    {color:green;}
</style>
```

Comment: @M.Gomez: What you've given is an Javascript code inside <script> tag in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should seperate `Jquery` and `Html` code... it should work then. Put all `Jquery` in a js file, not in your `Html` file